# foreach loop problem

Tags: php, foreach

Foreach don't work properly because in the a array there are multiple arrays and also objects.

For example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => modelItem Object
        (
            [name] => Name 1
            [option] => Array
                (
                    [0] => modelOption Object
                        (
                            [id] => 28383
                            [price] => 1.70
                        )
                )

            [quantity] => 2
        )

    [1] => modelItem Object
        (
            [name] => Name 2
            [option] => Array
                (
                    [0] => modelOption Object
                        (
                            [id] => 28398
                            [price] => 3.50
                        )
                )

            [quantity] => 2
        )

    [subtotal] => 10.40
    [deliveryArea] => modelDeliveryArea Object
        (
            [postcode] => BL2
        )

    [delivery] => 1
)
```

I want foreach only loop on modelItem Object and modelItem Object only, how can that be done?

I have tried doing this:

```
    <?php 
    foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
     echo  $item->name;
    foreach ($item->option as $o) {
    echo $o->price;
      }
      }
    ?>
```

It work fine but I also get an error:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

This is because of `subtotal`, `deliveryArea` I think.

Edit: Sorry, fixed the loop code - forgot to add { }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<?php 
foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
    if ($item instanceof modelItem) {
        echo  $item->name;

        if (isset($item->option) && is_array($item->option)) {
            foreach ($item->option as $o) {
                echo $o->price;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see what you mean, but we don't know which foreach loop is even erroring at this point. :|

Comment: The problem is, he's iterating over the first array (outer loop), and expecting all values (`$item`) to be a `modelItem`. Whereas the last entries are not.

Comment: do you know if `instanceof` is a synonym for `is_a()`? I know `is_a()` will check if the object has the specified class in its hierarchy. Is this the same with `instanceof`? (Besides being deprecated from php 5.0 - 5.2, but being undeprecated in 5.3 for some reason)

Comment: You can use both, I just tend to find `instanceof` visually more appealing ;P (and yes, `instanceof` wil check for parent classes and interfaces)

Answer (score 2):

Okay, the reason your code doesn't work, is because you are mixing types of your arrays. Which means you're going to have problems if you always expect `$item` to be a class. **IF** you can, I recommend restructuring your array so that your `modelItem` objects are in an array by themselves to make life easier.

If you cant... Try this:

```
<?php 
if (is_array($items)) {
    foreach ($items as $key => $item) {

        if(is_a($item, 'modelItem')) {            
            echo  $item->name;

            foreach ($item->option as $o) {
                echo $o->price;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As a side note `is_a()` is deprecated in php 5.0 - 5.2 and is now undeprecated in php 5.3. If you are using php 5.0 - 5.2 see yoshi's example.

Comment: add an `if ($item instanceof modelItem) {...}` around the body of the first loop. Or else it won't solve his problem

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add brackete's when I wrote a question, updated my question thanks. But is not a problem I were having.

Comment: @yoshi: shouldn't I solve it with is_array, as $items is an **array** OF modelItems. @user633378: which line is erroring?

Comment: @Neil: Yeah that was a typo when editing, you saw it for the 30seconds it was that way, lol.

Comment: @ohmusama: not quite, see my answer for what i meant.

Comment: Thank you for update, do you mean restructuring array something like this? Array
( [Items] => Array
            (
            [0] => modelItem Object
                (
                )

            [1] => modelItem Object
                (
                )
          ) )

Answer (score 0):

In array like this I would recommend to check like this:

```
if(isset($someVar))
{

}
```

or in your case check if is_array like this:

if(is_array($something))
   {

}

You can not loop trough a string in your case `subtotal`, `deliveryArea`

I hope it helps!